# Jenkins DSL multibranch pipeline github push trigger

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, multibranch-pipeline

I am using the jenkins dsl plugin multibranchpipeline job(https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/multibranchPipelineJob) to create a multi branch pipeline. I have created jenkinsfile which handles the build jobs for each branches. I couldnt figure out how the github push trigger can be enabled through pipeline as code. All the examples I could find are using the jenkins web UI or the pollscm option. Can someone please help on how this can be enabled through code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project was hosted in github.In jenkins dsl multibranchpipeline, i was using the git branchsource at first. Then push events were not triggering builds. After i started using github branchsource, push events were automatically generating builds.

ie.

```
multibranchPipelineJob('example') {
branchSources {
    git {
        id('12121212') // IMPORTANT: use a constant and unique identifier
        remote('https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git')
        credentialsId('github-ci')
        includes('JENKINS-*')
    }
}
}
```

Was changed to

```
multibranchPipelineJob('example') {
branchSources {
    github {
        id('23232323') // IMPORTANT: use a constant and unique identifier
        scanCredentialsId('github-ci')
        repoOwner('OwnerName')
        repository('job-dsl-plugin')
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @JoSSI thanks for pointing it out, I just accepted it as answer :)

Comment: Could you please update this answer with actual job-dsl, censored as needed, showing what the correct configuration looks like and where it goes?